# stop service for specified interval of time

Tags: android

I have a service that is fired using a set Repeating alarm after particular interval of time each day. Now I want the service to be fired only for the office time. i.e 8 am to 6 p.m. For this interval I want the service to fire at particular interval of time set by the user. After 6 pm it should stop and restart the next day at 8 am. Tried out almost everything available on the internet.Please give me some sample code for this.

Comment: In my opinion you can achieve it by using Scheduling Repeating Alarms( https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) .But for this you have to start an another service which will handle this alarm.

Answer (score 0):

You can fire alarm event every 2 hours. 
In receiver, check the time. If the time is within user entered time range(userEnteredTimeRange), run the service.If not, do not do anything.

I do not know what kind of service you need. If its just a quick background job, you can fire an IntentService.

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(ctx, MyAlarmReceiver.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

manager = (AlarmManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTimeInMillis(), SCHEDULEDING_TIME_IN_MS, pendingIntent);
```

in MyAlarmReceiver

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent arg1) {
    Log.e(TAG,"Alarm received");
    acquire(ctx);
    try {

    if(time in userEnteredTimeRange){ 
        ctx.startService(new Intent(ctx, YourService.class));
    }
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG,"error in starting service");
    }

}
```